# Inner div is invisible in a trapezoid shaped div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a div inside trapezoid shaped div.

But the inner div is invisible in anyway.

I also tried z-indexes.

```css
.trapezoid
{
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255,0,0,0.2) transparent;
    border-width: 0px 10px 38px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0;
    width: 40px;
    background-size: 430px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.innerIcon
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid" title="Fire Range Down">
     <!-- This inner div is invisible -->
 <div class="innerIcon"></div>
</div>
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: I haven't fully figured it out yet, but it is something to do with the `overflow: hdden` property on `.trapezoid`

Comment: @RobFos you are right. `overflow: hidden` was the original problem in my css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **trapezoid** is made up of **just border**, so it does not have a **height** ( height:0px specified in css). so `overflow:hidden` was **causing the problem** which is removed . Setting `position:absolute` to **inner div** and `postion:relative` to **trapezoid** will do the trick.

> Here is the updated code:

```css
.trapezoid {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) transparent;
  border-width: 0px 10px 38px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 40px;
  background-size: 430px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*New Css */
  position: relative;
}

.innerIcon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid" title="Fire Range Down">
  <!-- This inner div is invisible -->
  <div class="innerIcon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.innerIcon
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 39px;
        height: 38px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

Comment: Just adding `position: absolute` shows innerIcon div but it disturbs its position.